# how to POST data in appspot when Admin add a post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I am new in wordpress. I have an wordpress site where Admin can add post.But when he will add a post, a GET method submission should be also done to appspot `http://jhal-muri.appspot.com/sendAll?emailId=emailid&mssg=msg` .

How can I do that? I know that I have to change the add_post options in admin panel of wordpress But I don't know how to do.

Comment: By the way, from what I see about your server, it does not seem to receive a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Wordpress**

You can declare the form as `POST`. Then, construct your URL string as `http://jhal-muri.appspot.com/sendAll?emailId=emailid&mssg=msg` where `emailId` and `mssg` parameters will automatically become `GET`. The rest of the `input` names and values will become `POST`.

**Sample Code**

```
<form method="post" acion="http://jhal-muri.appspot.com/sendAll?emailId=emailid&mssg=msg">
<input type="text" value="" name="emailId" />
<input type="text" value="" name="msg" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send All" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where come form the JSP and Servlet ? I am using wordpress- it is php. I have no configuration problem with appspot.I just need to modify the wordpress back-end.How can I do it?

Comment: You are right. Here is a sample form that you can post for Wordpress.